# fetching multiple rows and display in json

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a PHP code like:

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check2)) {
  // $leadarray[] = $row2;
  $service_id[$i] = $row2['service_id'];
  $row1['service_id'][$i] = $service_id[$i];
  $service_name[$i] = $row2['service_name'];
  $row1['service_name'][$i] = $service_name[$i];
  $i++;
}
$leadarray[] = $row1;
$trimmed1['leaddetails'] = str_replace('\r\n', '', $leadarray);
echo json_encode($trimmed1);
```

getting output like

```
{
  "leaddetails": [
    {
      "service_id": [
        "7",
        "2"
      ],
      "service_name": [
        "Past Control Services",
        "Civil Finishing"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

I want output like:

```
"service_id": [
  1:  "7",
  2: "2"
],
"service_name": [
  1: "Past Control Services",
  2: "Civil Finishing"
],
```

or

```
[
  "service_id":  "7",
  "service_name": "Past Control Services",
  "service_id":  "2",
  "service_name": "Civil Finishing",
]
```

Comment: The second option is not possible, an array can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: [
  "service_id1":  "7",
  "service_name1": "Past Control Services",
  "service_id2":  "2",
  "service_name2": "Civil Finishing",
]  is this option is possible or not?

Comment: how can i write code for this output?

Comment: What's the point of adding these 1, 2? It's the same as 0, 1.

Answer (score 0):

`$trimmed1` is considered an object when passing it to `json_encode` (associative array in PHP) because you explicitly give it a key (considered an object property in JSON):

```php
$trimmed1 = [];
$trimmed1['leaddetails'] = 'foobar';
```

This will result in `json_encode` encoding `$trimmed1` into an object:

```
{
   "leaddetails": "foobar"
}
```

To get your desired result, have `$trimmed1` be considered an ARRAY when passed to `json_encode`.

```php
$trimmed1[] = str_replace('\r\n', '', $leadarray); // push instead of assign
```

Answer (score 0):

second option is not posible
you can make like this
`[{"service_id":"7", "service_name":"Past Control Services"}, {"service_id":"2", "service_name":"Civil Finishing"}]`

Comment: use class
ex:
`class Data{
$service_id;
$service_name;
}
$obj = new Array();
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check2)){
$data = new Data();
$data->service_id = $row2['service_id'];
$data->service_name = $row2['service_name'];
array_push($obj, $data);
}
echo json_encode($obj);`

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the bove code, correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"service_id":"7", "service_name":"Past Control Services"}, {"service_id":"2", "service_name":"Civil Finishing"}]
```

using class for make like that

```
class Data{ 
  $service_id; 
  $service_name; 
} 

$obj = new Array(); 
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check2)){ 
  $data = new Data(); 
  $data->service_id = $row2['service_id']; 
  $data->service_name = $row2['service_name']; 
  array_push($obj, $data); 
} 
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: this code is oops .could you help me to convert this code for procedural  programming?

Answer (score 0):

Create the 2-dimensional array first. Then push onto the nested arrays during the loop.

```
$result = ["service_id" => [], "service_name" = []];
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check2)) {
    $result["service_id"][] = $row["service_id"];
    $result["service_name"][] = $row["service_name"];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```